# Best data-structure for holding incremental values?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have to make a function that returns the spells a character has.

So I have 3 parameters: a level (an int from 1-50), an enum representing a character class (only 8 classes) and an enum representing a race (3-4 races).

This function has to return an array with spell IDs. The higher the level, the more spells a character has.

What I did so far is hard-coded everything, but when I have to modify something it is a mess. I don't know what kind of data-structure best suits my needs without recurring to horrible `if`s that are hard to change/mantain.

Also, the language is C# and I am using Xna/.NET 4.0

#### Update

```
public static int[] ListOfSpells(int level, CharacterClass chClass, CharacterRace chRace)
{
    switch (chClass)
    {
        case CharacterClass.Mage:
            return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        case CharacterClass.Knight:
            return new int[] { 2, 5, 6 };
        case CharacterClass.Paladin:
            return new int[] { 3, 5, 6, 2 };
        default:
            return new int[] { };
    }
}
 
// classes
 
public enum CharacterClass : short
{
    Mage = 0x00,
    Warlock,
    Priest,
 
    Monk,
    Knight,
    Assassin,
 
    Paladin,
    Hunter,
    Warrior
}
 
// races
 
public enum CharacterRace : short
{
    Human = 0x00,
    Elf
}
```

Comment: Could you provide any example?

Comment: this is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/FLLDJ3CT without taking account the character level, if the level passed as argument is higher, the character will have more spells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database if definitly what you need. You can maybe make it works with `IEnumerable`/`Array` now, but database will gave you the flexibility that you want for the future of your game.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what kind of data-structure best suits my needs without recurring to horrible 
>   ifs that are hard to change/mantain.

A simple trivial array, alternativels a table in a database.

Fields:

- Spell ID
- Character
- Class
- Level
- Description blablabla...

Then filter by matching condition.

And I suggest NOT returning an array - that is useless. make the method IEnumerable, then you CAN ToArray() it if needed, or just run along it.

Comment: Plus, one could `yield return` data from a `IEnumerable`-returning method, a feature too often overlooked.

Comment: Thati s waht i meant with "make the method IEnumerable" - you only need to make an array when you actually NEED it - quite often you may not.